# Order files by tags in file name

Tags: linux, bash, file, directory-structure

I got a list of files in my folder that I want to order:

```
Rock, World - SongTitle - Interpret.mp3
Rock, Acoustic, SingerSongwriter - SongTitle2 - Interpret.mp3
Rock, Acoustic - SongTitle3.mp3
SingerSongwriter, World - SongTitle4.mp3
```

The result should look like this:

```
storage/
- Rock, World - SongTitle - Interpret.mp3
- Rock, Acoustic, SingerSongwriter - SongTitle2 - Interpret.mp3
- Rock, Acoustic - SongTitle3.mp3
- SingerSongwriter, World - SongTitle4.mp3
tags/
- Rock/
  - LINK TO: storage/Rock, World - SongTitle - Interpret.mp3
  - LINK TO: storage/Rock, Acoustic, SingerSongwriter - SongTitle2 - Interpret.mp3
  - LINK TO: storage/Rock, Acoustic - SongTitle3.mp3
- World/
  - LINK TO: storage/Rock, World - SongTitle - Interpret.mp3
  - LINK TO: storage/SingerSongwriter, World - SongTitle4.mp3
- Acoustic/
  - LINK TO: storage/Rock, Acoustic, SingerSongwriter - SongTitle2 - Interpret.mp3
  - LINK TO: storage/Rock, Acoustic - SongTitle3.mp3
- SingerSongwriter/
  - LINK TO: storage/SingerSongwriter, World - SongTitle4.mp3
  - LINK TO: storage/SingerSongwriter, World - SongTitle4.mp3
```

I outlined the script that shall handle that for me:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p tags;
mkdir -p storage;

for file in *; do
        #Grab Tags from the file name
        tags=$(echo $file | sed 's/ - /\n/g'); # Doesn't work as it should

        #                                                               #
        #  This is just blind, can't say if it works, but should(TM)..  #
        #                                                               #

        #Move file to storage folder
        mv $file storage/$file;

        #Foreach Tag:
        while read -r tag; do
                #Create tag folder if it doesn't exist yet.
                mkdir -p tags/$tag;
                #Create Symbolic Link
                ln -s storage/$file tags/$tag/$file;
        done <<< $tags;
done
```

**Question**: How will I need to adjust my script so that it will work? I'm a little boon in bash scripting so please don't blame me..

Comment: `tags=$(echo $file | grep -Eo "^[^-]*")` ?

Comment: I think you should clarify if  you literally mean to sort the words `One`, `Two`, `Three` (which, if you expect to goto 100, people won't code for free ;-) .. Or if you really mean "subject area tags", like `Rock`, `90s`, `Asian`. ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I meant `TagOne`, `TagTwo`, `TagThree`.. These real tags are obviously not real tags. I got them seperated in *fast*, *slow*, *acoustic*, *Action* etc..

Comment: Yes, well `tag` is common to all of them, so you would have to sort `one`, `two` `three`, which didn't make too much sense. Thanks for clarifying, but I think you'll want to change your Q to match some of your examples of real tag values. Good luck.

Comment: @Aaron that looks fine, thank you. Next step will be to replace all the `, ` with `\n` so the while loop can work with that. Appending `tags=$(echo $tags | sed -e $'/, /\n/');` after the grep statement didn't work, but dropped **sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `\**... :/

Comment: @shellter Changed that.

Comment: You need the `s/pattern/replace/flags` syntax for a search&replace. Also you can (if you want) do it in one line : `tags=$(echo $file | grep -Eo "^[^-]*" | sed 's/, /\n/g')`

Comment: @Aaron nope, that doesn't create newlines but just replaces `\n` in the line..

Comment: Hu? `tags=$(echo "Rock, World - SongTitle - Interpret.mp3" | grep -Eo "^[^-]*" | sed 's/, /\n/g'); echo "$tags"` works just fine. Notice the quotes around the `$tags` reference though : if you don't use them, bash will remove the newlines

Comment: Works, @Aaron! Gonna post the result as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After working around, this is my answer to the thread.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p tags;
mkdir -p storage;

for file in *; do

        #Grab Tags from the file name
        tags=$(echo $file | grep -Eo "^[^-]*" | sed -e 's/, /\n/g');

        #                                                               #
        #  This is just blind, can't say if it works, but should(TM)..  #
        #                                                               #

        #Move file to storage folder
        mv "$file" "storage/$file";

        #Foreach Tag:
        while read -r tag; do
                #Create tag folder if it doesn't exist yet.
                mkdir -p tags/$tag;
                #Create Symbolic Link
                ln -s "storage/$file" "tags/$tag/$file";
        done <<< "$tags";
done
```